# Quiz Template with "Username"

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have to build quiz in flash for desktop. I am using a `quiz` template which is already inbuilt in flash. I have placed "`Username`" and "`password`" in the `first frame`. I have been able to verify the username and password but now the `quiz` doesn't go past the welcome page when I test `movie`. As well as I need to save the result of various iterations of the quiz under different username so that an admin can see it later. I would like to save the scores in such a way that the score stays even if the flash movie is closed. I found some solutions through Google, but they mostly deal with browsers and web servers. Since I am building a desktop application, I can not use those. I am newbie in `flash`. If some one can please help me with it will be grateful. Any ideas? suggestions?

Ganga

Comment: I'm afraid your description is not specific enough for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

game_data.data.(variable) is saved data. Say we want to save your score. game_data.data.last_score = score //This saves last_score at the value of score Say we want to load your score. score = game_data.data.last_score // This loads score at the value of last_score

game_data.data is only saved locally, use API on a website to save server-sided i.e. Kongregate;

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I have created a new quiz with "user name" and "password". I need to save that result in my hard drive. Is it possible to do so?. I have no idea regarding this. Can you please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes it'll be saved but only locally so the data will be on the hard drive and not the game itself.

Comment: Yes, I need the result of student data alone, not the entire quiz. Is it possible ? if so how to do ? can you give some idea ?. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't use other's engines if you don't understand them. 
I'm guessing the first page looks like so:
[Insert Username] - Input text (username_input)
[BUTTON] - Button... (button1)

Your question isn't very specific.
Here's an engine you can run just from the button
If "admin" is typed, click and the last user's name will appear.
If "admin" is still typed, click again to show the last user's score.
Click counter will reset to 0.

Paste this in frame1:

```
click1 = 0
button1.onRelease = function() {if(username_input.text == "admin"){
if (click1 == 1) {
username_input.text = game_data.data.last_score
click1 = 0
}
username_input.text = game_data.data.inputted_username
game_data.flush
click1++
} else {game_data.data.inputted_username = username_input.text}
```

Paste this in frame 3?? Your code isn't shown...

```
onEnterFrame = function() {
if (index >= questions.length){
game_data.data.last_score = score
game_data.flush ()
gotoAndStop (2)
```

You just didn't specify enough, hope this helped anyways. If you need anymore help just ask or if you need a quiz engine, I have my own.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not sure I correctly understand what exactly `game_data` is. If possible could you give me your quiz engine to study?

Comment: Look at my latest question for it. My e-mail's lorcanO33@gmail.com if you need me to explain it.